# Mounting NFS synchronously on boot

Tags: boot, nfs

I've added the following line to my `/etc/fstab`:

```
server:/srv/homes /home nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr,hard,auto 0 0
```

As you can see, /home needs to be mounted during the boot or users won't have an access to their home directory.

Unfortuately, Ubuntu seems to push mounting to the background and therefore /home is mounted approximately one minute after login screen appears. How can I make it wait for successful mount?

PS. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I would try adding `remote-filesystems`, emitted by `mountall.conf`, to the "starts on" conditions of `lightdm.conf`.

Comment: @enzotib sadly this won't work, because mountall will emit remote-filesystems immediately, and then mountall-net will finish the job, and emit mounted events for specific mountpoints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In lightdm's upstart job (/etc/init/lightdm.conf), add a mounted event so it looks a bit like this:

```
start on ((filesystem
           and runlevel [!06]
           and started dbus
           and (drm-device-added card0 PRIMARY_DEVICE_FOR_DISPLAY=1
                or stopped udev-fallback-graphics))
           and mounted MOUNTPOINT=/home
          or runlevel PREVLEVEL=S)
```

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing a similar problem after upgrading to 12.04 and solved it by adding the `nfsvers=3` option to the fstab entry for the NFS mount. The NFS filesystem was being exported using version 3 and there appears to be a problem in Ubuntu 12.04 and 11.10 with detecting that since version 4 is tried first. See the following bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nfs-utils/+bug/891825